# MySQL integer IN parameter being converted to 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL stored routine that has an IN parameter that is of type INTEGER (IN p_user_id INTEGER). If the user is creating a new user I pass p_user_id in as '' otherwise if the user is updating a user, I pass in the user_id of the user being edited. My issue with this is that when p_user_id is coming in as '' it is getting converted to 0. I've dumped the user id out right before PHP sends the value to MySQL (and the value is '') and dumped it out right at the beginning of the MySQL routine and the p_user_id is now 0. Can I get some insight for how to handle this so that I can have the p_user_id IN parameter be NULL. Thanks in advance!

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$functionCalled = $_GET['function'];

function userMaintMerge()
{   
    $userMaintUserId = $_GET['userMaintUserId'];
    $userMaintStep = $_GET['userMaintStep'];
    $userMaintFirstName = $_GET['userMaintFirstName'];
    $userMaintMI = $_GET['userMaintMI'];
    $userMaintLastName = $_GET['userMaintLastName'];
    $userMaintUserType = $_GET['userMaintUserType'];
    $userMaintSchoolId = $_GET['userMaintSchoolId'];
    $userMaintGrade = $_GET['userMaintGrade'];
    $userMaintLogin = $_GET['userMaintLogin'];
    $userMaintLogin = $_GET['userMaintPassword1'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli($_SESSION['dbaddress'],$_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['dbpword'],$_SESSION['database']);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    if (!$SelectUser = $mysqli->query("call MergeUser('$userMaintUserId','$userMaintStep','$userMaintFirstName','$userMaintMI','$userMaintLastName','$userMaintUserType','$userMaintSchoolId','$userMaintGrade','$userMaintLogin','$userMaintPassword1',@error)")) 
    {
        echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
}
?>
```

MySQL stored routine:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MergeUser`(IN  p_user_id      INTEGER
,IN  p_step         VARCHAR(10)
,IN  p_first_name   VARCHAR(100)
,IN  p_mi           VARCHAR(5)
,IN  p_last_name    VARCHAR(100)
,IN  p_user_type    INTEGER
,IN  p_school_id    VARCHAR(25)
,IN  p_grade        VARCHAR(2)
,IN  p_login        VARCHAR(25)
,IN  p_password     VARCHAR(25)
,OUT p_error        VARCHAR(1) 
)
BEGIN

    insert into rjh_log values ('',p_user_id,sysdate());

    IF p_step = 'add' THEN

        INSERT INTO USERS
                    ( USER_ID
                    , LOGIN
                    , FIRST_NAME
                    , MI
                    , LAST_NAME
                    , USER_TYPE_ID
                    , GRADE
                    , SCHOOL_ID
                    , PASSWORD
                    , ACTIVE_FLAG
                    ) 
             VALUES ( NULL
                    , p_login
                    , p_first_name
                    , p_mi
                    , p_last_name
                    , p_user_type
                    , p_grade
                    , p_school_id
                    , p_password
                    , 'Y'
                    ) ;

    ELSE

        UPDATE USERS
           SET LOGIN = p_login
             , FIRST_NAME = p_first_name
             , MI = p_mi
             , LAST_NAME = p_last_name
             , USER_TYPE_ID = p_user_type
             , GRADE = p_grade
             , SCHOOL_ID = p_school_id
             , PASSWORD = p_school_id
         WHERE USER_ID = p_user_id;

    END IF;

END
```

Comment: Post your code. Somewhere, the string is being cast to an int, which any string not beginning with a numeric value will will cast to 0.

Comment: @Michael I edited the question with code now included.

Comment: You're not escaping your query parameters; consider using prepared statements or proper escaping to avoid sql injection holes

Comment: `$userMaintLogin = $_GET['userMaintPassword1'];` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$userMaintUserId = ($_GET['userMaintUserId'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintUserId']);
$userMaintStep = ($_GET['userMaintStep'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintStep']);
$userMaintFirstName = ($_GET['userMaintFirstName'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintFirstName']);
$userMaintMI = ($_GET['userMaintMI'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintMI']);
$userMaintLastName = ($_GET['userMaintLastName'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintLastName']);
$userMaintUserType = ($_GET['userMaintUserType'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintUserType']);
$userMaintSchoolId = ($_GET['userMaintSchoolId'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintSchoolId']);
$userMaintGrade = ($_GET['userMaintGrade'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintGrade']);
$userMaintLogin = ($_GET['userMaintLogin'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintLogin']);
$userMaintLogin = ($_GET['userMaintPassword1'] == "" ? "NULL" : $_GET['userMaintPassword1']);
```